# login to dropbox with curl ( user login )

Tags: php, curl, dropbox

Am trying to log in to Dropbox as a user using cURL and PHP.

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
$data = array(
    't'=>'hxdlvCcN7SKKcfKCvpEO8-s2',
    'lhs_type'=>'anywhere',
    'login_email'=>'myemail@mail.com',
    'password'=>'mypass',
    'login_submit'=>1,
    'remember_me'=>'on',
    'login_submit_dummy'=>'Sign in'
);

// set cURL options and execute
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.dropbox.com/login?lhs_type=anywhere");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
$request_token_response = curl_exec($ch);       
var_dump($request_token_response );
```

I get 403 page with this text:

```
It seems you tried to do something we can't verify. Did you log into a different Dropbox account in a different window? Try clicking here to go back to the page you came from, or just go home.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using [Dropbox's Api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers)?

Comment: am using api for uploading and everything and everything works ok, but they have no api methods for user login , they are sending user to their website for login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, and there's a current class available to make it easy.  https://github.com/jakajancar/DropboxUploader/

It's as easy as

```
require 'DropboxUploader.php';
$uploader = new DropboxUploader('email@address.com', 'password');
```

The `$uploader->loggedin` will return if you are logged in or not.

Comment: thx this works, i had to change class a bit , i have set loggedin to public and login() to public also , then u need to call login() method so 
require 'DropboxUploader.php';
$uploader = new DropboxUploader('email@address.com', 'password');
$uploader->login();
var_dump($uploader->loggedin);

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that the 't' value can only be used once. You need to call for a fresh one each time you go to log in.

If you look at the class suggested in the other post, you will see that it does just that.